# NodeJs and Ejs Pass Arrays to page

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, locomotivejs

I am trying to pass an array to an .ejs page, however when I try use

```
var test ="<%= data %>";
console.log(test);
```

I get the output

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object
```

Console.log on the nodejs file works fine, but its when I try console.log client side it messes up.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The issue is likely with `<%= data %>`, rather than `console.log()`. If you check the result client-side, you'll probably see:

```
var test ="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...";
```

When you simply *print* an `Array`, this will just [`.join()` the elements](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2), calling `.toString()` on each. [And](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2):

```
new Object().toString() === "[object Object]"
```

To output the data so it can be consumed, you can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var test = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
```

This takes advantage of JSON's syntax being based on JavaScript's synax to output an [`Array` literal of `Object` literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals):

```
var test = [{"prop":"value"},...];
```

Comment: I can't get this to work properly if I don't use `<%- JSON.stringify() %>` instead of `<%= JSON.stringify() %>`.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks. Forgot about that.